# Thonny py5-mode Error when running a code

Tags: python, thonny

I just tried to use py5 in thonny, but everytime i have the py5 mode on and try to run a code i get a bunch of error messeges, i dont really know what they mean so maybe somebody can help me out ?
thanks in advance

This is the error im always getting

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\schwe\AppData\Roaming\Thonny\plugins\Python310\site-packages\py5_tools\tools\run_sketch.py", line 52, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\schwe\AppData\Roaming\Thonny\plugins\Python310\site-packages\py5_tools\tools\run_sketch.py", line 44, in main
    imported.run_code(
  File "C:\Users\schwe\AppData\Roaming\Thonny\plugins\Python310\site-packages\py5_tools\imported.py", line 135, in run_code
    _run_code(
  File "C:\Users\schwe\AppData\Roaming\Thonny\plugins\Python310\site-packages\py5_tools\imported.py", line 259, in _run_code
    _run_sketch(sketch_path, classpath, exit_if_error)
  File "C:\Users\schwe\AppData\Roaming\Thonny\plugins\Python310\site-packages\py5_tools\imported.py", line 196, in _run_sketch
    import py5
  File "C:\Users\schwe\AppData\Roaming\Thonny\plugins\Python310\site-packages\py5\__init__.py", line 84, in <module>
    from py5_tools.magics import load_ipython_extension  # noqa
  File "C:\Users\schwe\AppData\Roaming\Thonny\plugins\Python310\site-packages\py5_tools\magics\__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from .drawing import DrawingMagics, DXFDrawingMagic
  File "C:\Users\schwe\AppData\Roaming\Thonny\plugins\Python310\site-packages\py5_tools\magics\drawing.py", line 27, in <module>
    from IPython.display import display, SVG, Image
  File "C:\Users\schwe\AppData\Roaming\Thonny\plugins\Python310\site-packages\IPython\__init__.py", line 51, in <module>
    from .core.application import Application
  File "C:\Users\schwe\AppData\Roaming\Thonny\plugins\Python310\site-packages\IPython\core\application.py", line 26, in <module>
    from IPython.core import release, crashhandler
  File "C:\Users\schwe\AppData\Roaming\Thonny\plugins\Python310\site-packages\IPython\core\crashhandler.py", line 27, in <module>
    from IPython.core import ultratb
  File "C:\Users\schwe\AppData\Roaming\Thonny\plugins\Python310\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py", line 101, in <module>
    import stack_data
  File "C:\Users\schwe\AppData\Roaming\Thonny\plugins\Python310\site-packages\stack_data\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .core import Source, FrameInfo, markers_from_ranges, Options, LINE_GAP, Line, Variable, RangeInLine, \
  File "C:\Users\schwe\AppData\Roaming\Thonny\plugins\Python310\site-packages\stack_data\core.py", line 19, in <module>
    from stack_data.utils import (
  File "C:\Users\schwe\AppData\Roaming\Thonny\plugins\Python310\site-packages\stack_data\utils.py", line 11, in <module>
    from asttokens import ASTText
ImportError: cannot import name 'ASTText' from 'asttokens' (C:\Users\schwe\AppData\Local\Programs\Thonny\lib\site-packages\asttokens\__init__.py)
```

Answer (score 0):

I received a response from the py5 developer via Github. They also provided an explanation but it goes over my head, something about "The Python library asttokens is used for parsing syntax trees and syntax highlighting. It is not used by py5 but it might be used by Jupyter Notebook and/or JupyterLab.". They also provided a solution here:
[enter link description here](https://github.com/tabreturn/thonny-py5mode/issues/42#issuecomment-1366770155)